# How can I put an image in a rectangle(blank) by using the drop and drop?

Tags: javascript

Hi i'm trying to make some web.
It's a simple game 
just drag the answer to the blank and if is the correct answer, the answer is in the blank.

**ex image ,,, like this )**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ny0Is.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtYOR.png)

This is my current code.
I can drag the img. but can't put in answer to the blank.

html code -----

```js
var css_test_idx = 10;
var pt1 = $("#pt1");


$('#n1')
  .draggable().css('cursor', 'move').mousedown(function() {
    $(this).css('z-index', css_test_idx);
    css_test_idx++;
  });

$("#n1")
  .draggable({
    stop: function() {
      $(this).animate({
        top: 0,
        left: 0
      }, 250, 'easeOutBack');

    }
  })
  .css('cursor', 'move');


$('#n2')
  .draggable().css('cursor', 'move').mousedown(function() {
    $(this).css('z-index', css_test_idx);
    css_test_idx++;
    $("#n2")
      .draggable({
        stop: function() {
          $(this).animate({
            top: 0,
            left: 0
          }, 250, 'easeOutBack');
        }
      })
      .css('cursor', 'move');
  });

$('#n3')
  .draggable().css('cursor', 'move').mousedown(function() {
    $(this).css('z-index', css_test_idx);
    css_test_idx++;

    $("#n3")
      .draggable({
        stop: function() {
          $(this).animate({
            top: 0,
            left: 0
          }, 250, 'easeOutBack');

        }
      })
      .css('cursor', 'move');

  });

$('#n4')
  .draggable().css('cursor', 'move').mousedown(function() {
    $(this).css('z-index', css_test_idx);
    css_test_idx++;

    $("#n4").draggable({
      stop: function() {
        $(this).animate({
          top: 0,
          left: 0
        }, 250, 'easeOutBack');

      }
    }).css('cursor', 'move');

  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>Insert title here</title>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    #leftbox {
      float: left;
      width: 170px;
      height: 170px;
      height: 250;
      margin: 5px;
      border: 3px solid blue;
    }
    
    #clock {
      position: static;
      width: 900px;
      height: 650px;
      margin-top: 50px
    }
    
    #box {
      position: relative;
      margin-left: 300px;
    }
    
    #n1 {
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      margin-left: 50px
    }
    
    #n2 {
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      margin-left: 50px
    }
    
    #n3 {
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      margin-left: 50px
    }
    
    #n4 {
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      margin-left: 50px
    }
    
    #blank {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100px
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <center><img id="clock" src="image/clock.png"></div>
  </center>
  <div id="leftbox"></div>
  <center>
    <div class="box">
      <img id="n1" src="image/n1.png" />
      <img id="n2" src="image/n2.png" />
      <img id="n3" src="image/n3.png" />
      <img id="n4" src="image/n4.png" />
    </div>
  </center>

  <script src="temp2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

-- you can't run this code here because i use node express.

help~

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Node.

Comment: Not sure if this would help you but I had a question for a class once related to something like this https://github.com/FranciscoAT/CSI3140_assignments/blob/master/assignment_4/A4_Q4_Trindade_7791605.txt (it's a JS file but it's .txt because the prof wanted to us to email him solutions for whatever reason). I think this is what you are looking for? But it won't have grid locking.

Comment: @Francisco hi.  I can't open the link you gave to me.. can you check the link again?

Comment: https://github.com/FranciscoAT/CSI3140_assignments/blob/master/assignment_4/A4_Q4_Trindade_7791605.js